# Canvas to dataURL Image Png quality not working

Tags: javascript, canvas, png, todataurl, pixel-ratio

I've been trying to convert an HTML5 canvas to dataUrl with a low quality because I have to transfer the dataURL files through a server but wether I do

```
dataURL = document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL("image/png", 1);
```

or

```
dataURL = document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL("image/png", 0.00001);
```

the quality doesn't change, the string length stay the same and when I download back that image in both cases its the same quality, any idea what I am doing wrong?

this is an example but the canvas I am doing this has a much better pixelRatio and is well detailled

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const button = document.querySelector('button')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
canvas.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = window.innerHeight

ctx.fillStyle = 'red'
ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100)
ctx.fillStyle = 'green'
ctx.fillRect(60, 60, 80, 80)
ctx.fillStyle = 'white'
ctx.font = "bold 20px sans-serif"
ctx.fillText("What a square!", 0, 90)

document.getElementById("b1").addEventListener('click', () => {
  let data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png",0.000001);
  downloadImage(data, "low.png");
})

document.getElementById("b2").addEventListener('click', () => {
  let data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png",1.0);
  downloadImage(data, "high.png");
})

function downloadImage(data, filename = 'untitled.png') {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = data;
    a.download = filename;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
}
```

```html
<button id="b1">Save Low</button>
<button id="b2">Save High</button>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: That param only has an effect for lossy compression, i.e. jpeg and webp. PNG is lossless and therefore the concept of quality doesn't apply.

Comment: which formats is better in terms of visual quality/compression?

Comment: jpg is only good for photographs, for anything logo-like or featuring text, you should use something else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because PNG is a lossless format. You can't tune the quality because it is always 1.

From the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) :

> A Number between 0 and 1 indicating the image quality to use for image
>   formats that use lossy compression such as image/jpeg and image/webp.

Comment: which formats is better in terms of visual quality/compression?

Comment: @Woold file formats that support lossy compression are  image/jpeg and image/webp.